# Variable scope in Object

Tags: class, object, scope, this

```
class Hangman{
    constructor(lives){
        this.hintChoice=5;
        this.lives=lives;
        this.newGame();
        
    }
    newQuestion(){
        this.hintChoice=10;//PROBLEM LINE 
    }
    
    displayClue(){
        clueDiv.innerText='Clue -'+' '+ this.hintChoice; 
    }
}
```

When newQuestion() is called,why does the value of  this.hintChoice not change globally to 10?

Answer (score 0):

The value of `this` is determined by a lot of factors. In your example, you have a class and the only way of invoking a function inside it is to create an instance of the class.

The proper way of creating an instance of a class and invoking is as follows. If you want to know more, please read my blog here on the same here: https://dbwriteups.wordpress.com/2017/04/08/what-does-that-this-in-javascript-mean/

```js
class Counter {
    constructor(count) {
        this.count = count;
    }
    increment() {
        this.count++;
    }
    getCount() {
        return this.count;
    }

    setCount(value) {
        this.count = value;
    }
}

let counter = new Counter(5); // Instance of class created.
console.log(counter.getCount()); // Prints 5
counter.increment(); // Increments count to 6
console.log(counter.getCount()); // Prints 6
counter.setCount(10); // Sets count to 10
counter.increment();  // Increments count to 11
console.log(counter.getCount()); // Prints 11
```

Comment: Assuming I created a Hangman object, should the value of this.hintChoice change globally when newQuestion() is called by an event listener?

Comment: Yes, definitely. As I said, the value of `this` is assigned based on the calling context. If you go through the blog link in my answer you will be able to figure it out yourself.